# How to reuse route on query params change, but not on path params change in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

Say I have 2 routes `'/users'` and `/users/:id`. First one renders `UserListComponent` and second `UserViewComponent`.

I want to re-render component when navigating from `/users/1` to `/users/2`. And of course if I navigate from `/users` to `/users/1` and vice versa.

But I DON'T want to re-render component if I navigate from `/users/1?tab=contacts` to `/users/1?tab=accounts`.

Is there a way to configure router like this for entire application?

--

Update:

I'm importing RouterModule in AppRoutingModule like this:

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })`

I'm using Angular 12

Comment: what's your router module configuration? is `onSameUrlNavigation` set to `reload`?

Comment: relativeLinkResolution is set to 'legacy'. No other configuration is passed to RouterModule.forRoot

Comment: how do you assign your routes ? cause the changing the queryParameters shoiuld alreadt not rerender the component.

Comment: Yeah, changing query params doesn't cause rerender, and neither does changing **path** params - that's the part that doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Re-rendering would be inefficient, you should probably use observables to represent your data set over time

Comment: I agree with @maxime1992, it feels like you are working against the framework here.  I'm curious what your use case is to want to destroy and recreate the component.  Maybe show a sample of your component code.

Comment: @BizzyBob I have a large project with lot of "list and detail" pages and users can often navigate between detail pages without going back to list page. Until now I solved this problem by using custom route reuse strategy which never reuses routes. It's way simpler than listening for param changes in every component. But now I have one details page which displays some complex entity (takes a few seconds to load and render) and I'm using query params for storing some state (filters and stuff). But if I change query params entire page reloads (because of my route reuse strategy) [1/2]

Comment: So I thought there might be simpler solution than getting rid of custom route reuse strategy and adding listeners for path param changes in every component [2/2]

Comment: Interesting.  Can you show an example of what your component code looks like with the route strategy versus a sample of what it would look like if you "listen for route changes in every component".  I typically find listening to route params to be pretty clean, so I'm wondering if there is something more complex about your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of the Angular router is to preserve the current component when the URL matches the current route.

This behavior can be changed by using the [`onSameUrlNavigation`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation) option:

> Define what the router should do if it receives a navigation request
> to the current URL. Default is `ignore`, which causes the router ignores
> the navigation. This can disable features such as a "refresh" button.
> Use this option to configure the behavior when navigating to the
> current URL. Default is 'ignore'.

Unfortunately, this option is not fine-grained enough to allow `reload` for path params and `ignore` for query params.

So you have to subscribe both to the query params and the path params changes with something like this:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.renderLogic();
  this.route.params.subscribe(() => this.renderLogic());
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(() => this.renderLogic());
}

renderLogic() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, @Guerric P is correct, you can't completely re-render the component selectively like this, at least not without some trickery like subscribing to each event and then possibly blocking it for one scenario and not the other. Feel free to try something like that, but below is an alternative if you make use of resolvers to fetch your data.

What you *can* do is use [runGuardsAndResolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers) in your route configuration like so:

```
const routes = [{
  path: 'team/:id',
  component: Team,
  children: [{
    path: 'user/:name',
    component: User
  }],
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'pathParamsChange',
  resolvers: {...},
  canActivate: [...]
}]
```

This will, as the name suggests, run your guard resolver logic again. If you fetch data using resolvers and pass it into your components, you can update what your component displays only when the path or params change.